# manage city according to country selected in jquery autocomplete?

Tags: jquery

//for country

```
var objCountries = [];
var objSearchCountry = new Object();
objSearchCountry.CountryName = $("#txtCountry").val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "db.php?GetCountryList",
    data: {data:[]},
    dataType: "json",
    async:false,
    success: function(response)
    {
        if(response.IsError)
            alert(response.ErrorMessage);
        else
            objCountries = response;
    },
    error:function(response)
    {
        alert("Error: " + response.responseText);
    }
});

var newObjCountry = [];
for (var indexCountry in objCountries)
    newObjCountry.push(objCountries[indexCountry].CountryName);
$("#txtCountry").autocomplete({ source: newObjCountry });
```

when i select any country, i want its id so that i can pass this id, in city to get related cities.

```
$("#txtCountry").blur(function()
{
//for city
var objCities = [];
var objSearch = new Object();
objSearch.city_name = $("#txtCity").val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "db.php?GetCityList",
    data: {data:[]},
    dataType: "json",
    async:false,
    success: function(response)
    {
        if(response.IsError)
            alert(response.ErrorMessage);
        else
            objCities = response;
    },
    error:function(response)
    {
        alert("Error: " + response.responseText);
    }
});

var newObj = [];
for (var index in objCities)
    newObj.push(objCities[index].city_name);
$("#txtCity").autocomplete({ source: newObj });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: You can use $("#txtCountry").val(); to get the Country val and pass that in data to your GetCityList method .

Comment: tried but not working..:(

Comment: You're not storing the country ID anywhere.  When you create the autocomplete it only contains country names.  You need a select element instead.

Comment: in autocomplete i am fetching both countryid and countryname

Comment: Yes, but I assume the element `#txtCountry` is a text box?  Inspect it in your browser's development tools to see if it has any data attached to it.  If not, you only have the value to go by.  You may need to consider using a select instead of a text box.

Comment: yes its an textbox and it does not contain any data to it

Comment: @Ajinder Singh $("#txtCountry").val() gives me country name. How to get CountryID?

Comment: You can save CountryID in hidden field and access it from hidden field ...Otherwise you need to make an ajax request which returns the CountryId corresponding to that CountryName .

Comment: @AjinderSingh please tell me how to pass hidden field in jquery.

Comment: Pass hidden field means ? ...In your method GetCountryList you can return Both Country Name and Country ID ..and in response you get both.

Comment: @AjinderSingh please tell me how to return both?

Comment: Same as you are returning CountryName ...Also as Archer suggested you can use the Dropdown for Country instead of textbox ...

Comment: @AjinderSingh autocomplete is not working in dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need is to use on select event of autocomplete

Here is [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/SaDVm/1/)

```
 select : function(e, ui){
     alert("selected!" + ui.item.value);
     //rest of the code after selection goes here
 }
```